# How to have an image appear/pop up on top of a default image? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have an image appear on top of the default image("images/giphy.gif") while a certain keyboard key is pressed. For example, when the A key is pressed, I want the image to appear.

However, I was able to have an image("images/giphy1.gif") appear under the default image while inputing keys on a text box, which is not the point because I want it on top of/or cover the default image

*P.S. Im still a beginner and have no prior experience in coding. I'm also doing this in Dreamweaver 8

Heres my code for the function:

```
<img src="images/giphy.gif" width="800" height="400" alt=""/>
<input type="text" onkeypress="myFunction()">
```

**JS :**

```
window.addEventListener("keypress", checkKeyPressed, false);

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("IMG");

    x.setAttribute("src", "images/giphy1.gif")
    x.setAttribute("width", "705");
    x.setAttribute("width", "591");
    x.setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock");

    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
```

EDITED:

```
<img src="images/giphy.gif" id="default-img" width="800" height="400" alt=""/>
<input type="text" onkeypress="myFunction()">

<script>

window.addEventListener("keypress", checkKeyPressed, false);


function myFunction() {
var x = document.createElement("IMG");
x.setAttribute("src", "images/giphy1.gif")
x.setAttribute("width", "800");
x.setAttribute("height", "400");
x.setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock");
document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could insert the new img at the top of your body using :

```
document.body.insertBefore(x,document.body.firstElementChild);
```

Hope this helps.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("IMG");

    x.setAttribute("src", "https://www.stib-mivb.be/irj/go/km/docs/horaires/2/images/20150629/2.gif")
    x.setAttribute("width", "30");
    x.setAttribute("width", "30");
    x.setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock");

    document.body.insertBefore(x,document.body.firstElementChild);
}
```

```html
<br>
<img src="https://www.stib-mivb.be/irj/go/km/docs/horaires/1/images/20150629/1.gif" alt=""/>
<br>
<input type="text" onkeypress="myFunction()">
```

**Edit without using input :**

```html
<br>
<img src="https://www.stib-mivb.be/irj/go/km/docs/horaires/1/images/20150629/1.gif" alt=""/>

<script>
  document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownBody, false);

  function keyDownBody(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if(keyCode==65) {
      myFunction();
    }
  }

  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("IMG");

    x.setAttribute("src", "https://www.stib-mivb.be/irj/go/km/docs/horaires/2/images/20150629/2.gif")
    x.setAttribute("width", "30");
    x.setAttribute("width", "30");
    x.setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock");

    document.body.insertBefore(x,document.body.firstElementChild);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I'm still a bit confused of where to insert the code you've provided. Anyway my edited code is posted above. Also, I'm trying to get rid of the text box completely, and have the image appear when I press the keyboard key "A" , for example.

Answer (score 0):

add only one eventlistener

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="myFunction()">
```

and

no need of `window.addEventListener("keypress", checkKeyPressed, false);`

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki my point was only to show not need of both eventListeners :) sorry if it was wrong

Answer (score 0):

`appendChild` always adds content to the end. There is no `prepend` method in VanillaJS. So you should to use `insertBefore` method. For example, like this:

```
document.body.insertBefore(x, document.body.firstChild);
```

But in real life, you have to wrap your default image and insertBefore it into your container.